# Double false for Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide an input field if the td doesn't have a value.

I know we can have a condtition like this:

```
${condition ? true : false}
```

but how can I have an inline operator like this?

```
${condition ? true : false && false}
```

Example:

```
${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : " " && $('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide()}
```

The html is similar to this:

```
`<td>
${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : " " && $('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide()}
</td>
`<div><input id="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: `" " && $('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide()` What is the reason for having a empty space? I mean, it doesnt assign or anything?

Comment: It sounds like this would be much easier to understand with a simple `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt so i have a table which sometimes brings back 2 values, and sometimes one per object. So it shows a space instead of an "undefined" when value 2 doesnt exist. hopefully that makes sense. value 1 is always true but not always value 2. and if value 2 doesnt exist, I need it to hide the textbox.

Comment: @JamesLong its in between like 20 <td></td> hence i wonder if its possible to add 2 actions to the else statement in an inline if/else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you want the truthy result to be the description, and the falsy result to be `" "` **and** to have the side-effect of removing the style attribute from `#textbox` and hiding it.

**I strongly recommend not doing that.** Side-effects like that are extremely hard to debug and maintain.

But if you really want to, make the side-effect first:

```
`<td>
${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : $('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide() && " "}
</td>
`<div><input id="textbox"></div>
```

That works because `hide` returns the jQuery object, which is truthy, so the `(object) && " "` expression results in `" "`. Or as [James Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557019/james-long) points out, you could use the comma operator instead, and then the return value of `hide` wouldn't matter: `${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : ($('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide(), " ")}` (you don't actually need those `()`, but it's already confusing enough, and it's even more confusing without them, so...).

**But again, I wouldn't.** Instead, I'd just do:

```
`<td>
${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : " "}
</td>
`<div><input id="textbox"></div>
```

...and then just before or just after this template literal, have

```
if (!JsonObject) {
    $('#textbox').removeattr("style").hide();
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be `${JsonObject ? JsonObject.Description : ($('#textbox').removeAttr("style").hide(), "")}` (harder to read and understand IMO) but +1 for recommending a simple `if`

Comment: A nice Stackoverflow feature would be to see what other are currently answering. This would help me to not write 20 lines and then see that someone already answer the same but quicker :D. But anyway your explanation was better than mine so thank you for this :)

Comment: @JamesLong - Good point, yes, that way the return value wouldn't matter. (If you want to make it **more** confusing, you don't even needs those `()`. ;-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the second law of thermo-dynamic-HTML: confusion always increases